# Bash: Check if argument is given (e.g. is there the argument "-a" ?)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script, which should accept 2 arguments. (-s and -d). If the -d argument is not given, i want to delete my debug file. Same with -s. How do I check if either $1 or $2 is -s or -d?

Shure with 2 arguments i could do that "Brute Force":

```
if test $1 != "-d" && test $2 != "-d" then
rm $debug
fi
```

But if I have more than 2 it will get complicated, so what is the proper way to check if any of the arguments is "-d" ?

Comment: Not a `for` loop for parsing arguments, but a `while` loop.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf A While-loop from $# downwards to $1 ? Isn't there a version more elegant?

Comment: No, a `while` loop is by far the best! and it's elegant too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getopt(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) to parse command-line options in a shell script.

Comment: [`getopt` is not very good](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035). In Bash it's much better to use the builtin `getopts`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf but he is right if he says that i should not check for arguments i should check for Options

Answer (score 2):

Here's an oversimplified arguments parsing for you so you get the idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg_s=0
arg_d=0

show_help() { printf 'Help me\n'; }
show_version() { printf 'version -∞\n'; }
show_usage() { printf 'Usage: %s [-s|-d|-v|-h] [args...]\n' "${0##*/}"; }
invalid_option() { printf >&2 "you can't use option %s. You dumbo\n" "$1"; show_usage; exit 1; }

while (($#)); do
    [[ $1 = -- ]] && { shift; break; }
    [[ $1 = -?* ]] || break
    case $1 in
        (-s) arg_s=1 ;;
        (-d) arg_d=1 ;;
        (-h) show_help; exit 0 ;;
        (-v) show_version; exit 0 ;;
        (-*) invalid_option "$1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done

printf 'You passed the -s flag: %d\n' "$arg_s"
printf 'You passed the -d flag: %d\n' "$arg_d"
printf 'Remaining arguments:\n'
printf '   %s\n' "$@"
```

Note that it would need some extra work to handle flags like `-ds` that means `-d -s`<sup>1</sup>, a little bit of extra work to have options accepting parameters, and some extra work to handle long options. All this is doable without any major problems.

---

<sup>1</sup> you can have a look at my [mock `which`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642253/creating-a-which-command-in-bash-script/28647323#28647323) that has an argument parsing that supports that.

Comment: This only allows flags at the start of the command. For example if you pass `test -d blah` it will say `you passed the -d flag: 0`

Comment: @JID I don't understand your comment. If you run `./test -d blah` you'll get `You passed the -d flag: 1` and `Remaining arguments: blah`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant if you passed them three args like `./Script test -d blah`

Comment: @JID you're right. But it's not very difficult to handle this case either. I don't want to modify the script since OP's requirement seems rather simple (and some tools do exhibit this behavior). And did I mention the word _oversimplified_ in my answer? It does handle the mandatory `--` though `:)`.

Comment: @JID this is mentioned by POSIX, e.g., [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a basic loop as follow:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "$arg" = '-d' ]; then
        rm -f $debug
    fi
done
```

For more complex parsing, you should consider to use the builtin-command getopts

Comment: A `for` loop is not suited to argument parsing at all. If a switch takes an argument, you can't really handle that in a simple way. A `while` loop is by far superior for this task.