# Checking root integrity via a script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, redhat

Below is my script to check root path integrity, to ensure there is no vulnerability in PATH variable.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ ""`echo $PATH | /bin/grep :: `"" != """" ]; then
    echo "Empty Directory in PATH (::)" 
fi

if [ ""`echo $PATH | /bin/grep :$`""    != """" ]; then echo ""Trailing : in  PATH"" 
fi

p=`echo $PATH | /bin/sed -e 's/::/:/' -e 's/:$//' -e 's/:/ /g'`
set -- $p
while [ ""$1"" != """" ]; do
    if [ ""$1"" = ""."" ]; then
        echo ""PATH contains ."" shift
        continue
    fi
    if [ -d $1 ]; then
        dirperm=`/bin/ls -ldH $1 | /bin/cut -f1 -d"" ""`
        if [ `echo $dirperm | /bin/cut -c6 ` != ""-"" ]; then
            echo ""Group Write permission set on directory $1""
        fi
        if [ `echo $dirperm | /bin/cut -c9 ` != ""-"" ]; then
            echo ""Other Write permission set on directory $1""
        fi
        dirown=`ls -ldH $1 | awk '{print $3}'`
        if [ ""$dirown"" != ""root"" ] ; then
            echo $1 is not owned by root
        fi
    else
        echo $1 is not a directory
    fi
    shift
done
```

The script works fine for me, and shows all vulnerable paths defined in the PATH variable. I want to also automate the process of correctly setting the PATH variable based on the above result. Any quick method to do that.

For example, on my Linux box, the script gives output as:

```
/usr/bin/X11 is not a directory
/root/bin is not a directory
```

whereas my PATH variable have these defined,and so I want to have a delete mechanism, to remove them from PATH variable of root. lot of lengthy ideas coming in mind. But searching for a quick and "not so complex" method please.

Comment: You want to delete e.g. /usr/bin/X11 and /root/bin from your PATH variable, did i understand that correctly?

Comment: Don't use `ls`. Use the `stat` command. `stat -L -f %04Lp $file` will give you the octal mode of the file. Combine that with a mask, and you know if a permission bit is set or not: `perm=$(stat -L -f %04Lp $file)` to get the octal permission (`0755`), and then `(( perm & 0010))` to see if the group execute permission is set. And please, please format your code correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No offense but your code is completely broken. Your using quotes in a… creative way, yet in a completely wrong way. Your code is unfortunately subject to pathname expansions and word splitting. And it's really a shame to have an insecure code to “secure” your `PATH`.

One strategy is to (safely!) split your `PATH` variable into an array, and scan each entry. Splitting is done like so:

```
IFS=: read -r -d '' -a path_ary < <(printf '%s:\0' "$PATH")
```

See my [mock `which`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642253/creating-a-which-command-in-bash-script/28647323#28647323) and [How to split a string on a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/24426608#24426608) answers.

With this command you'll have a nice array `path_ary` that contains each fields of `PATH`.

You can then check whether there's an empty field, or a `.` field or a relative path in there:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#path_ary[@]};++i)); do
    if [[ ${path_ary[i]} = ?(.) ]]; then
        printf 'Warning: the entry %d contains the current dir\n' "$i"
    elif [[ ${path_ary[i]} != /* ]]; then
        printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not an absolute path\n' "$i"
    fi
done
```

You can add more `elif`'s, e.g., to check whether the entry is not a valid directory:

```
elif [[ ! -d ${path_ary[i]} ]]; then
    printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not a directory\n' "$i"
```

Now, to check for the permission and ownership, unfortunately, there are no pure Bash ways nor portable ways of proceeding. But parsing `ls` is very likely not a good idea. `stat` can work, but is known to have different behaviors on different platforms. So you'll have to experiment with what works for you. Here's an example that works with GNU `stat` on Linux:

```
read perms owner_id < <(/usr/bin/stat -Lc '%a %u' -- "${path_ary[i]}")
```

You'll want to check that `owner_id` is `0` (note that it's okay to have a dir path that is not owned by root; for example, I have `/home/gniourf/bin` and that's fine!). `perms` is in octal and you can easily check for `g+w` or `o+w` with bit tests:

```
elif [[ $owner_id != 0 ]]; then
    printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not owned by root\n' "$i"
elif ((0022&8#$perms)); then
    printf 'Warning: the entry %s has group or other write permission\n' "$i"
```

Note the use of `8#$perms` to force Bash to understand `perms` as an octal number.

Now, to remove them, you can `unset path_ary[i]` when one of these tests is triggered, and then put all the remaining back in `PATH`:

```
else
    # In the else statement, the corresponding entry is good
    unset_it=false
fi
if $unset_it; then
    printf 'Unsetting entry %s: %s\n' "$i" "${path_ary[i]}"
    unset path_ary[i]
fi
```

of course, you'll have `unset_it=true` as the first instruction of the loop.

And to put everything back into `PATH`:

```
IFS=: eval 'PATH="${path_ary[*]}"'
```

I know that some will cry out loud that `eval` is evil, but this is a canonical (and safe!) way to join array elements in Bash (observe the single quotes).

Finally, the corresponding function could look like:

```
clean_path() {
    local path_ary perms owner_id unset_it
    IFS=: read -r -d '' -a path_ary < <(printf '%s:\0' "$PATH")
    for ((i=0;i<${#path_ary[@]};++i)); do
        unset_it=true
        read perms owner_id < <(/usr/bin/stat -Lc '%a %u' -- "${path_ary[i]}" 2>/dev/null)
        if [[ ${path_ary[i]} = ?(.) ]]; then
            printf 'Warning: the entry %d contains the current dir\n' "$i"
        elif [[ ${path_ary[i]} != /* ]]; then
            printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not an absolute path\n' "$i"
        elif [[ ! -d ${path_ary[i]} ]]; then
            printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not a directory\n' "$i"
        elif [[ $owner_id != 0 ]]; then
            printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not owned by root\n' "$i"
        elif ((0022 & 8#$perms)); then
            printf 'Warning: the entry %s has group or other write permission\n' "$i"
        else
            # In the else statement, the corresponding entry is good
            unset_it=false
        fi

        if $unset_it; then
            printf 'Unsetting entry %s: %s\n' "$i" "${path_ary[i]}"
            unset path_ary[i]
        fi
    done

    IFS=: eval 'PATH="${path_ary[*]}"'
}
```

This design, with `if/elif/.../else/fi` is good for this simple task but can get awkward to use for more involved tests. For example, observe that we had to call `stat` early before the tests so that the information is available later in the tests, before we even checked that we're dealing with a directory.

The design may be changed by using a kind of spaghetti awfulness as follows:

```
for ((oneblock=1;oneblock--;)); do
    # This block is only executed once
    # You can exit this block with break at any moment
done
```

It's usually much better to use a function instead of this, and `return` from the function. But because in the following I'm also going to check for multiple entries, I'll need to have a lookup table (associative array), and it's weird to have an independent function that uses an associative array that's defined somewhere else…

```
clean_path() {
    local path_ary perms owner_id unset_it oneblock
    local -A lookup
    IFS=: read -r -d '' -a path_ary < <(printf '%s:\0' "$PATH")
    for ((i=0;i<${#path_ary[@]};++i)); do
        unset_it=true
        for ((oneblock=1;oneblock--;)); do
            if [[ ${path_ary[i]} = ?(.) ]]; then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %d contains the current dir\n' "$i"
                break
            elif [[ ${path_ary[i]} != /* ]]; then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not an absolute path\n' "$i"
                break
            elif [[ ! -d ${path_ary[i]} ]]; then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not a directory\n' "$i"
                break
            elif [[ ${lookup[${path_ary[i]}]} ]]; then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %s appears multiple times\n' "$i"
                break
            fi
            # Here I'm sure I'm dealing with a directory
            read perms owner_id < <(/usr/bin/stat -Lc '%a %u' -- "${path_ary[i]}")
            if [[ $owner_id != 0 ]]; then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %s is not owned by root\n' "$i"
                break
            elif ((0022 & 8#$perms)); then
                printf 'Warning: the entry %s has group or other write permission\n' "$i"
                break
            fi
            # All tests passed, will keep it
            lookup[${path_ary[i]}]=1
            unset_it=false
        done
        if $unset_it; then
            printf 'Unsetting entry %s: %s\n' "$i" "${path_ary[i]}"
            unset path_ary[i]
        fi
    done

    IFS=: eval 'PATH="${path_ary[*]}"'
}
```

All this is really safe regarding spaces and glob characters and newlines inside `PATH`; the only thing I don't really like is the use of the external (and non-portable) `stat` command.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you get a good book on Bash shell scripting. It looks like you learned Bash from looking at 30 year old system shell scripts and by hacking away. This isn't a terrible thing. In fact, it shows initiative and great logic skills. Unfortunately, it leads you down to some really bad code.

#### If statements

In the original Bourne shell the `[` was a command. In fact, `/bin/[` was a hard link to `/bin/test`.  The `test` command was a way to test certain aspects of a file. For example `test -e $file` would return a `0` if the `$file` was executable and a `1` if it wasn't.

The `if` merely took the command after it, and would run the `then` clause if that command returned an exit code of zero, or the `else` clause (if it exists) if the exit code wasn't zero.

These two are the same:

```
if test -e $file
then
    echo "$file is executable"
fi

if [ -e $file ]
then
    echo "$file is executable"
fi
```

The important idea is that `[` is merely a system command. You don't need these with the `if`:

```
if grep -q "foo" $file
then
    echo "Found 'foo' in $file"
fi
```

Note that I am simply running `grep` and if `grep` is successful, I'm echoing my statement. No `[ ... ]` are necessary.

A *shortcut* to the `if` is to use the *list operators* `&&` and `||`. For example:

grep -q "foo" $file && echo "I found 'foo' in $file"

is the same as the above `if` statement.

#### Never parse `ls`

You should never parse the `ls` command. You should use `stat` instead. `stat` gets you all the information in the command, but in an easily parseable form.

#### `[ ... ]` vs. `[[ ... ]]`

As I mentioned earlier, in the original Bourne shell, `[` was a system command. In Kornshell, it was an internal command, and Bash carried it over too.

The problem with `[ ... ]` is that the shell would first interpolate the command before the test was performed. Thus, it was vulnerable to all sorts of shell issues. The Kornshell introduced `[[ ... ]]` as an alternative to the `[ ... ]` and Bash uses it too.

The `[[ ... ]]` allows Kornshell and Bash to evaluate the arguments *before* the shell interpolates the command. For example:

```
foo="this is a test"
bar="test this is"
[ $foo = $bar ] && echo "'$foo' and '$bar' are equal."
[[ $foo = $bar ]] && echo "'$foo' and '$bar' are equal."
```

In the `[ ... ]` test, the shell interpolates first which means that it becomes `[ this is a test = test this is ]` and that's not valid. In `[[ ... ]]` the arguments are evaluated first, thus the shell understands it's a test between `$foo` and `$bar`. Then, the values of `$foo` and `$bar` are interpolated. That works.

#### For loops and `$IFS`

There's a shell variable called `$IFS` that sets how `read` and `for` loops parse their arguments. Normally, it's set to space/tab/NL, but you can modify this. Since each PATH argument is separated by `:`, you can set `IFS=:"`, and use a `for` loop to parse your `$PATH`.

#### The `<<<` Redirection

The `<<<` allows you to take a shell variable and pass it as STDIN to the command. These both more or less do the same thing:

```
statement="This contains the word 'foo'"
echo "$statement" | sed 's/foo/bar/'

statement="This contains the word 'foo'"
sed 's/foo/bar/'<<<$statement
```

#### Mathematics in the Shell

Using `((...))` allows you to use math and one of the math function is masking. I use masks to determine whether certain bits are set in the permission.

For example, if my directory permission is `0755` and I *and* it against `0022`, I can see if user read and write permissions are set. Note the leading zeros. That's important, so that these are interpreted as octal values.

Here's your program rewritten using the above:

```
#! /bin/bash

grep -q "::" <<<"$PATH" && echo "Empty directory in PATH ('::')."
grep -q ":$" <<<$PATH && "PATH has trailing ':'"

#
# Fix Path Issues
#
path=$(sed -e 's/::/:/g' -e 's/:$//'<<<$PATH);

OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":"
for directory in $PATH
do
    [[ $directory == "." ]] && echo "Path contains '.'."
    [[ ! -d "$directory" ]] && echo  "'$directory' isn't a directory in path."
    mode=$(stat -L -f %04Lp "$directory")       # Differs from system to system
    [[ $(stat -L -f %u "$directory") -eq 0 ]] &&  echo "Directory '$directory' owned by root"
    ((mode & 0022)) && echo "Group or Other write permission is set on '$directory'."
done
```

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do or mean about *PATH Vulnerabilities*. I don't know why you care whether a directory is owned by root, and if an entry in the `$PATH` is not a directory, it won't affect the `$PATH`. However, one thing I would test for is to make sure all directories in your `$PATH` are absolute paths.

```
[[ $directory != /* ]] && echo "Directory '$directory' is a relative path"
```

Comment: thank you som much for your simple yet detailed explanation of the problems in the code. Helped a lot.

Comment: HI, what is '%04Lp' supposed to be? or what version of stat to check on what distro?

Answer (score 1):

The following could do the whole work and also removes duplicate entries

```
export PATH="$(perl -e 'print join(q{:}, grep{ -d && !((stat(_))[2]&022) && !$seen{$_}++ } split/:/, $ENV{PATH})')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @kobame's answer but if you don't like the `perl`-dependency you can do something similar to:

```
$ cat path.sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH="/root/bin:/tmp/groupwrite:/tmp/otherwrite:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
echo "${PATH}"

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
for path in ${PATH}; do
    [ -d "${path}" ] || continue
    paths=( "${paths[@]}" "${path}" )
done

while read -r stat path; do
    [ "${stat:5:1}${stat:8:1}" = '--' ] || continue
    newpath="${newpath}:${path}"
done < <(stat -c "%A:%n" "${paths[@]}" 2>/dev/null)
IFS=${OIFS}

PATH=${newpath#:}
echo "${PATH}"
```

---

```
$ ./path.sh
/root/bin:/tmp/groupwrite:/tmp/otherwrite:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Note that this is not portable due to `stat` not being portable but it will work on Linux (and Cygwin). For this to work on BSD systems you will have to adapt the format string, other Unices don't ship with `stat` at all OOTB (Solaris, for example).

It doesn't remove duplicates or directories not owned by `root` either but that can easily be added. The latter only requires the loop to be adapted slightly so that `stat` also returns the owner's username:

```
while read -r stat owner path; do
    [ "${owner}${stat:5:1}${stat:8:1}" = 'root--' ] || continue
    newpath="${newpath}:${path}"
done < <(stat -c "%A:%U:%n" "${paths[@]}" 2>/dev/null)
```